# What is the difference between int *p[5] and a pointer obtained through malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I cant seem to understand the difference between:

```
int *p[5]
```

and

```
int *p;
p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
```

I just started learning C-ANSI pointers and I understand the basics but until a few hours ago I thought the two previous lines were equivalent.

I know the 1st one is an array of pointers of type int (capable of storing 5 int pointers), but isn't the last line the same?

Or is it just another way of writing:

```
int arrayX[5];
int *p;
p = arrayX;
```

but dynamically allocated instead?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mind the precedence. `int *p[5]` parses as `int *(p[5])` which is an array of 5 pointers to int. A pointer to an array of 5 ints would be `int (*p)[5];` instead.

Comment: Last line `int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);` leads to `p` pointing to 5 `int`.

Comment: I guess you mean to ask about `int p[5]` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *p[5]` declares an array of 5 pointers of type `int`.  So, `p[0]` is itself a pointer to an `int` (and so are `p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]`).  Then, `p[i][0]` will be some `int` value (assuming `p[i]` points to some allocated region of memory).  Depending on how much memory `p[i]` points to, you will be able to access a number of `int` values via `p[i][j]`.

When you make the call to `malloc()`, you are asking for enough memory to hold `sizeof(int) * 5` bytes, which is essentially 5 `int` values.  If the allocation does not fail, `malloc()` returns a pointer to that allocated memory.  So, when you write:

```
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

`p` is a pointer to a region of memory that has been allocated to store 5 `int` values.  Therefore, `p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]` all have `int` values.

In summary:

```
    int *p[5];    /* p[i] is a POINTER to INT, and p[i][j] is an INT */
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);    /* p[i] is an INT */
```

Comment: So:  

>`int arrayX[5];  
>int *p;  
>p = arrayX;`  
  
Is the same as:
>`int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);`  

But the first one is created in the stack and the last one is created on the heap, right?

Comment: @totito88 Assuming that `arrayX` was declared in some function (e.g. `main()`), then yes, the contents of `arrayX` will be on the stack.  When using `malloc()`, the variable `p` is itself on the stack, but the memory that it points to is located on the heap.